# Non blocking requestin in django save models

Tags: django, python-3.x, request

I would like to send to a server the json version of a model.

but i would like to send it with a non blocking request

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ''' On save, update timestamps '''
    if not self.id:
        self.created = timezone.now()
    r = requests.post('http://localhost:9040/put_img/', json=self.to_json())
    return super(IdImg_Data, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Any idea how to do that in the save function ?

thanks and regards